# WSO2 EMM - How to config project

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

When i develop with WSO2 EMM, i don't understand how to config project to run on local. I has config run on local success, but i don't go to the address same as the tutorial: [Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbwhOOXBaFw/)
Please tell me how to make it.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of the EMM are you working on? You are referring to an old tutorial which uses an older version of EMM. Refer the documentation of the latest version [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/WSO2+Enterprise+Mobility+Manager)

Answer (score 0):

Every EMM version has the same URL if you are using a fresh pack with out modifying the offset configuration in carbon.xml the default url will be as following,

- https://localhost:9443/emm

the tutorial you are referring is for EMM 1.*.* release. The latest version of EMM is 2.2.0 which is available in [EMM product page](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/).

The functionalities are most likely the same with new and improved UI and much more features and higher performances.So its best if you can use the new version to get started with wso2 EMM.